# How to find the current content scale factor in my top UIView?

Tags: ios

I know that to get the default device scale factor, I do this:

`CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`

But how do I get the current scale factor for my main/top view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIView has a ["`contentScaleFactor`" property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentScaleFactor) that you can take advantage of.

You can access it via something like:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
if(keyWindow)
{
    UIViewController *rootViewController = keyWindow.rootViewController;

    CGFloat scale = rootViewController.view.contentScaleFactor;
}
```

Comment: I might be using a different scale, for instance a 3D rendering app I might use 1.5 so my iPad backing surface is actually 1024*1.5 x 768*1.5

Comment: turns out UIView has a scale factor too (just noticed this).

Comment: would this be correct? `CGFloat scale = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].contentScaleFactor;`

Comment: No, because you're referencing a UIWindow (which doesn't have a scale factor).  You could get the scale factor from the "`contentView`" property of that key window, though.

Comment: I'm having problems with that - can you (or anyone) provide a code example?

Comment: sure... there you go.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I didn't figure on having to go through the controller, and UIWindow _is_ a UIView so it had a scale factor but it was not a useful value.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS and iPadOS support external displays, the following code will return the scale of the screen the view is actually presented on.

**Swift 5.2**

```
view.window?.screen.scale
```